# An activity file in a dependency module cannot be found

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-ndk, dependencies

This is the pathway to the activity file in a dependency module:

```
app/src/main/dependencies/base/src_java/com/project
/test/base/BaseActivity.java
```

This is the pathway to my main activty:

```
app\src\main\java\com\kernel\app\experiment\ExperimentActivity.java
```

In my ExperimentActivity.java file I attempt to import the TestActivity.java file which belongs to the Test module that is a dependency to my Experiment project. Here is the code:

```
package com.kernel.app.experiment;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.project.test.base.TestActivity;


public class ExperimentActivity extends TestActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
}
```

Here is the file I am attempting to import:

```
package com.project.test.base;

// imports are written here
import org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity;

public class TestActivity extends SDLActivity implements
    MagnetSensor.OnCardboardTriggerListener, NfcSensor.OnCardboardNfcListener,
    Choreographer.FrameCallback {

// more code ...

}
```

However I keep getting these errors:
In my gradle console I get an error message that reads:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

And in my Messages Gradle Build, i get the following error messages:

```
Error:(12, 30) error: package com.project.test.base does not exist
Error:(38, 40) error: cannot find symbol class TestActivity
Error:(39, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(41, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(42, 5) error: cannot find symbol method getWindow()
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.kernel.app.experiment">
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".ExperimentActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is my module build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kernel.app.experiment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild{
               // cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
               arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-19"
            }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug{
        ndk{
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
            // abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
        }
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk{
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
            // abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild{
        //path "CMakeLists.txt"
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
    }
}

repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs System.env.FIREBASE_SDK + '/libs/android'
  }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/android', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp:firebase_messaging_cpp@aar'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How do I get the build system to find the correct pathway to import this missing package?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add your module to your project using

1-file>new>import module

2- add

```
 apply plugin: 'MODULE_NAME'
```

in your build.gradle, so it will be

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kernel.app.experiment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild{
               // cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
               arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-19"
            }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug{
        ndk{
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
            // abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
        }
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk{
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
            // abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild{
        //path "CMakeLists.txt"
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
    }
}

repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs System.env.FIREBASE_SDK + '/libs/android'
  }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/android', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp:firebase_messaging_cpp@aar'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'MODULE_NAME'
```

3- and in setting.gradle

```
include ':app', ':MODULE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the library to Android Studio

1. Open your project in Android Studio.
2. Download the dependency module (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip).
3. Create a folder "testProject" in your project directory.
4. Copy and paste the dependency module code to your testProject folder.
5. On the root of your project directory create/modify the settings.gradle file.

   `include 'MyApp', ':testProject:TestLibrary'`
6. gradle clean & build/close the project and reopen/re-import it.
7. Edit your project's build.gradle to add this in the "depencies" section:

   `dependencies {
     //...
     compile project(':subProject:FreemiumLibrary')
   }`
8. public class ExperimentActivity extends TestActivity.
9. build